# Previous state persists momentarily after page with React component is reloaded

Tags: reactjs

I have a React component (Google Calendar-like program for booking meetings or tasks) which begins at an initial state based on the current week. It used to be so that whenever the page is loaded, the calendar always starts at the current week. However recently I added a feature so that if you navigate 3 weeks into the future and create a meeting, a cookie is logged and the page refreshes and stays "in the future" by setting the cookie date as state. However if you navigate 3 weeks into the future, don't book anything, then check out a different page before returning to the calendar page, it will load with current week as starting state. I have the cookies working correctly, but the problem is that when you navigate into the future, visit another page, and then come back to the calendar page, it shows the "old" state of the future for about a half second before showing the proper "new" state of current day/ week. I have tried different mounting and unmounting methods but none have fixed the issue. No matter what, the page always shows the calendar data and dates for "the future" before correctly showing current week data.

```
var MasterSchedule = React.createClass({
  getInitialState() {
    var start = Cookies.get('master_week_start');
    var end = moment(start).endOf('week').format("YYYY-MM-DD");
    var referrer = this.props.referrer;
    if (start != null && referrer.includes("schedule")) {
      return {
        currentWeekStart: start,
        currentWeekEnd: end,
        users: this.props.users,
        closures: []
      }
    } else {
      Cookies.remove('master_week_start');
      return {
        currentWeekStart: moment().startOf('week').format("YYYY-MM-DD"),
        currentWeekEnd: moment().endOf('week').format("YYYY-MM-DD"),
        users: this.props.users,
        closures: []
      }
    }
  },
...
render() {
var currentWeekStart = this.state.currentWeekStart;
var currentWeekEnd = this.state.currentWeekEnd;
var monday = moment(currentWeekStart).add(1, 'day').format("M.DD");
var offset = 0;
var currentWeek = [];
while (offset < 5) {
  currentWeek.push(moment(monday).add(offset++, 'd').format("M.DD"));
};
...
return (
  <div>
    <div className="date-nav">
      <div className="col s12">
        <div className="row card task-card light-gray valign-wrapper">
          <div className="col s2 m1">
            <i className="black-text right material-icons md-36">date_range</i>
          </div>
          <div className="col s6 m3 l2">
            {this.renderDateDisplay()}
          </div>
          <div className="col s1">
            <a className="black-text right" id="prevWeek" onClick={prevWeek}><i className="material-icons">keyboard_arrow_left</i></a>
          </div>
          <div className="col s1">
            <a className="black-text" id="upcomingWeek" onClick={upcomingWeek}><i className="material-icons">keyboard_arrow_right</i></a>
          </div>
          <div className="col s0 m4 l6">
          </div>
          <div className="col s2 m2 l1">
            <a className="black-text" id="resetWeek" onClick={resetWeek}>Today</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div className="row frame-row dark-gray-text">
      <div className="row frame-row">
        <div className="col s2 hide-on-small-only left">
          <p className="padding-top-user">User</p>
        </div>
        <div className="col s2 center hide-on-small-only">
          <p className="no-bottom-margin">Monday</p>
          <p className="no-top-margin">{currentWeek[0]}</p>
        </div>
        <div className="col s2 center hide-on-small-only">
          <p className="no-bottom-margin">Tuesday</p>
          <p className="no-top-margin">{currentWeek[1]}</p>
        </div>
        <div className="col s2 center hide-on-small-only">
          <p className="no-bottom-margin">Wednesday</p>
          <p className="no-top-margin">{currentWeek[2]}</p>
        </div>
        <div className="col s2 center hide-on-small-only">
          <p className="no-bottom-margin">Thursday</p>
          <p className="no-top-margin">{currentWeek[3]}</p>
        </div>
        <div className="col s2 center hide-on-small-only">
          <p className="no-bottom-margin">Friday</p>
          <p className="no-top-margin">{currentWeek[4]}</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div className="divider"></div>
    {this.renderUserRows()}
    <div className="divider"></div>
  </div>
```

From here the MasterSchedule renders a basic calendar layout, rows for each user in the calendar, columns for each day in the week, and then individual components for meetings or bookings as appropriate. So all in all there 4 children below this.

This is the calendar briefly rendering the "future" after I've returned to the page:

[image: This is the calendar briefly rendering the "future"]

And then it returns back to current week:

[image: And then it returns back to current week]

But I need to get rid of the momentary re-render of old "future" data. Thanks!

Comment: It would be helpful to see the JSX implementation of the calendar.

Comment: I added more details. For example I cannot understand why even `{currentWeek[i]}` always renders with the previous data as it is right in the parent component, not even in a child component.

Answer (score 0):

An update can be caused by changes to props or state.  `componentWillReceiveProps()` will help you to solve the problem. 
checkout [this](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html) page for more life cycle method of react component